# How to force range 0 to 100 in xtics in Matplotlib when range of y is only up to 8

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to have a fixed set of xtics in a horizontal bar graph in Mathplotlib, which go from 0 to 100, with intervals of 10.

I have tried various ways, but no matter what I put, it still only shows 0 and the max number, but does not show the rest because the range of the plotted numbers only go to about 8 (see variable perc), but I need to show that there is very little advancement.

If I change the interval to 2, it shows up to 8, but it should show up to 100 and the bars should be very small. The code is below along with photos which show the error. I do not have a photo of what I need because I can't get it to work.

UPDATE: the comment given below resolved this problem, by moving ptl.barh to right below the variable x.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

perc = [6, 3, 8, 7, 2, 6, 5, 6, 7, 7, 5, 8, 2, 6, 3]

emails = ['email1@gmail.com', 'email2@gmail.com', 'email3@gmail.com', 'email4@gmail.com', 'email5@gmail.com', 'email6@gmail.com', 'email7@gmail.com', 'email8@gmail.com', 'email9@gmail.com', 'email10@gmail.com', 'email11@gmail.com', 'email12@gmail.com', 'email13@gmail.com', 'email14@gmail.com', 'email15@gmail.com']

ran4 = [0,10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90,100]

x = np.arange(len(emails))
plt.style.use('fivethirtyeight')
plt.yticks(ticks=x,labels=emails,rotation=0,fontsize=9)
plt.xticks(np.arange(0, 100, 10))
plt.ylabel("EMPLEADOS")
plt.xlabel("AVANCE")
plt.title("AVANCES EN LOS CURSOS PARA LOS EMPLEADOS")
plt.barh(x, perc, height=0.25, color='green', label='AVANCE')
plt.legend()
plt.tight_layout()
plt.subplots_adjust(left=0.26, right=0.95, bottom=0.11, top=0.9)
plt.show()
```

[image: image1]

[image: image2]

Comment: Move `plt.barh(x, perc, height=0.25, color='green', label='AVANCE')`  to just **after** `x = np.arange(len(emails))`  - before any of the other plotting statements.

Comment: Yes, that resolved the problem.